# Removing "text/html" for rendered xml from React Component

Tags: javascript, xml, reactjs, rss

I am trying to create an rss feed.  The only problem now is when I try to validate it, I need to remove the "text/html" for it to work.  Not sure how to do this with my react component here:

```
const Feed = Component({
    render() {
        return (
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <rss version="2.0">
                    <channel>
                        <title>Test</title>
                        <link>test</link>
                        <description>test</description>
                        <item>
                            <title>test</title>
                            <link>test</link>
                            <guid>test</guid>
                            <pubDate>Tues, 23 Aug 2016 10:00:00 CDT</pubDate>
                            <description>test</description>
                        </item>
                    </channel>
                </rss>
        );
    }
})

export default Feed
```

When I look at the source through Chrome Dev tools this is what I see for mine, notice the doctype is html, not xml:

[image]

Then when you compare that to any other rss feed such as egghead.io, here's how theirs looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/reactjs/jHjrma95bn8

> This isn't currently possible. We've done some thinking about how to make that easier, but right now we have 2 places where we keep track of what type of nodes we support (hopefully just 1 place in the future). The first is the JSX transform which hardcodes the list of tags it supports. The second is what is exposed off of React.DOM.*. If you want to fork and extend, that's one option. We're focused on HTML/SVG at the moment, but I would definitely be interested in some way to make all of these injectible and share the list of supported tags.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2278

> No, sorry. React DOM is primarily designed for HTML.

Comment: I'll just have to go straight up file then mysite/myfeed.xml